# HttpConduit in Jaxws

Tags: java, web-services

I have this little code

```
serviceName = new javax.xml.namespace.QName(uri,routine);
portName = new javax.xml.namespace.QName(uri,port);
try{
    url = new java.net.URL(wsdlURL);
}
catch(java.net.MalformedURLException muwe){
    muwe.printStackTrace();
}

java.net.Authenticator.setDefault(new java.net.Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected java.net.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new java.net.PasswordAuthentication(
            user,
            pwd.toCharArray());
    }
});
service = javax.xml.ws.Service.create(url,serviceName);
request="";
request+="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>";
request+=......//xml request

dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName,javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage.class,javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
content = new java.io.StringReader(request);
input = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(content);
message = javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL).createMessage();
message.getSOAPPart().setContent(input);
headers = message.getMimeHeaders();
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction",soap_azione);
message.saveChanges();
response = dispatch.invoke(message);
```

but I don't succeed to find a way to pull `HTTPConduit` to set the correct timeout.
I already tried with:

```
dispatch.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", rectime);
    dispatch.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", conntime);
```

this:

```
 dispatch.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", rectime);
    dispatch.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", conntime);
```

and the last one:

```
dispatch.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", rectime);
dispatch.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", conntime);
```

but I didn't get the desired behaviour.

How can I get `HTTPConduit` from the previous code?
In the examples there is always an interface but my request didn't have this shape.

Thank you.

Best Regards.

Comment: HTTPConduit is an Apache CXF feature, not available with default JAX WS. Can you tell which JAX WS implementation you are using?

Comment: Yes, infact I already loaded the cxf jar into my project in order to obtain a link with httpconduit and set the corect values for the timeout.